# python str() function result differs from __str__() function's result

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am updating a hobby app, written in Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 that stores railway history data in json. I used it upto now to work on british data.

When starting with french data I encountered a problem which puzzles me. I have a class `CompaniesCache` which implements `__str__()`. Inside that implementation everything is using str's. Let's say I instantiate a `CompaniesCache` and assign into a variable `companies`. When I, in IPython2, give the command `print companies`, I get an error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' in    position 184: ordinal not in range(128)".

Alright, that is not strange. Testing. `str(companies)` reproduces the error, as expected. But, `companies.__str__()` succeeds without problems, as does `print company.__str__()`. What is wrong here ?

Here the code of the __str__ method of the CompaniesCache object:

```
class CompaniesCache(object):                                                       
    def __init__(self, railrefdatapath):       
        self.cache = restoreCompanies(railrefdatapath)                                             

    def __getitem__(self, compcode):                                                                                     
        return self.cache[compcode.upper()]                                                                              

    def __str__(self):                                                                
        s = ''                                                                            
        for k in sorted(self.cache.keys()):                                                                              
            s += '\n%s: %s' % (k, self[k].title)                                                                
        return s
```

This is the code for the CompaniesCache object, which contains Company objects in its cache dict. The Company object does not implement the __str__() method.

Comment: Could you please include some of your code?

Comment: Your `__str__` method is returning a `unicode` object with non-ascii characters in it.

Comment: Can you add a string sample?

Comment: First you have a bug in `s += '\n%s: %s' % (k, self[k].title)` -> `s += '\n%s: %s' % (k, self[k].title())`

Comment: @YonatanKiron: title is a member of the Company object, not a getter. Bad style ?

Comment: @user2357112 but why does CompaniesCache.__str__() work?

Comment: @MichielRademakers Yep, especially when you are using it in `__str__`, I was thinking you meant `str.title` function

Comment: @YonatanKiron - what makes you think `title` is a function? I don't see that specified anywhere.

Comment: Since it's "passed" to a string, So I assumed it's a string, and string has title function. but NVM, it's not related to your question :)

Comment: Ah, now I get the bad style remark ... I was unaware that title is a standard str function, so the choice of the member name is definitely bad. Thanks.

Comment: @MichielRademakers Exactly :)

Answer (score 4):

`str` doesn't just call `__str__`. Among other things, it validates the return type, it falls back to `__repr__` if `__str__` isn't available, and **it tries to convert `unicode` return values to `str`** with the ASCII codec.

Your `__str__` method is returning a `unicode` instance with non-ASCII characters. When `str` tries to convert that to a bytestring, it fails, producing the error you're seeing.

Don't return a `unicode` object from `__str__`. You can implement a `__unicode__` method to define how `unicode(your_object)` behaves, and return an appropriately-encoded bytestring from `__str__`.

Comment: This sounds good !  The problem is that the whole thing started out as british only. It is the french data that is injecting unicode data. It seems I have to refactor the app to work with unicode only, and maybe port it to python3.

Answer (score 0):

Using [maxpolk answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334767/3592113)
I think all you should do is setup your environment variable to

```
export LC_ALL='en_US.utf8'
```

All and all I think you can find your answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Comment: Tried this, but it does not alter anything. My environment is already US utf8.